# Returning to the US after previous overstay

Tags: visas, usa, overstaying

I travelled to the US as a tourist and lived there illegally for almost 9 years. I was never arrested, or had any trouble with the law. I was never deported. I paid my taxes (had a TIN), had a job, bank account, etc.. About 9 years ago I decided to leave as I was tired of living like that, not able to be legal, in fear of deportation and loosing everything.

Will I be allowed to enter US now, as I hold a different passport other than the one I overstayed with?

Comment: Did you abandon your other account? Or are you the same person?

Answer (score 0):

The change of passport *might* help if you decide to lie about your previous history on the application and if the US doesn't have the data to identify you anyway. You would be in the same situation as before, always at risk of being caught. And if they do, you will get an even longer ban.

Telling the truth might get your application denied, or not. If the visa is granted, you can travel without worry.

Needless to say, my advice is to tell the truth. Or find another place for your travels.

Comment: Note that if they catch you lying (and they certainly take steps to try), you'll be banned, I believe for 10 years, and you'll have an even harder time ever getting a visa after that. Even if you now hold a different passport, you still have the same biographical data, fingerprints, facial recognition profile, etc...

Comment: @ZachLipton: Material misrepresentation is a lifetime ban

Comment: @ZachLipton was the US collecting fingerprints or other biometrics in the late 1990s?

Comment: @phoog I believe they were for BCC's from Mexico at least, so there were at least some biometrics going into the system then. I'll agree it's certainly possible they don't have any on file for the OP.